# MySQL - Duplicate rows by different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
id | user_id | job | type
```

**The scenario is as following:**

"A person in a company is offering his skills, another person is looking for skills. They can fill in their offerings and searches. After filling this in, they need to see the matches between what they are looking for and others are offering."

- So "`job`" is a string, f.e. "creating backup","repairing bike"
- So "`type`" is a string, f.e. "searching", "offering"

Is it possible to get these matches with one query?

** edit **

```
id | user_id | job           | type
---|---------|---------------|----------
1  | 1       | Create backup | searching
2  | 1       | Format osx    | searching
3  | 2       | Create backup | offering
4  | 1       | Program PHP   | offering
```

I want to do a query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = 1 AND type = 'offering'` ... with a result that provides me an array of all the other users that are offering this. So that the user has a page with all the results of people that are offering the job that he is searching.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the results you want

Comment: Cant get your objective from this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you all user offering skills which are searching. Try it:

```
SELECT o.* FROM Table1 s 
INNER JOIN Table1 o 
ON s.job = o.job
WHERE s.type = 'searching'
AND o.type = 'offering'
AND s.user_id = (The user who is searching)
```